# Swift + Sqlite : Why getting data from sqlite return optional Value?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sqlite

My code below is to get data from sqlite but I don't know why I get optional value with my data. Can you help me? You can also look at my screenshot to make clear.

```
func getDataFromSqlite(index : Int) ->Array<String>{

    var items = [String]()
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data", ofType: "sqlite")!
    let db = try! Connection(path, readonly: true)
    let stmt = try! db.prepare  ("SELECT name FROM engcate WHERE t_id = \(index)")
    for row in stmt{
        print("row \(row)")
        items.append("\(row)")
    }
    return items

}
```

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: you need to unwrap the optional before append

Comment: @MartinR, NO. It does not have optional(....) in my database

Comment: Try `if let name = row[0] as? String { items.append(name) }`

Comment: @MartinR, now it is working ur last code.

Comment: Thank you so much: @Anbu.Karthik and MartinR

Comment: The values might be NULL.